# Eclipse error: error has occured see log file

Tags: java, eclipse, github

I went to the file and the info below is what it displayed. I was attempting to add web tools for github repo functionality and then it crashed and would love to not uninstall and risk losing my code that I am working on. Is there a way to fix this without causing any harm on the projects in eclipse?
this is the log file:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.VersionParser.parse(VersionParser.java:83)
at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.Version.create(Version.java:96)
at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.Version.parseVersion(Version.java:164)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.LocationProperties.create(LocationProperties.java:88)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.handleRemoteIndexFile(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:735)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadIndexFile(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:724)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:119)
at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadIndexFile(CachingRepositoryManager.java:388)
at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:187)
at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager$Metadata.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:495)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:110)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:105)
at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.doLoad(LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.java:126)
at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.runModal(LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.java:110)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.PreloadingRepositoryHandler$1.runModal(PreloadingRepositoryHandler.java:84)
at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.ProvisioningJob.run(ProvisioningJob.java:188)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)

Comment: That's not the log file. Check your workspace for a `.metadata` directory with a `.log` file inside of it--*that's* the log file. Also, how were you trying to add web tools?

Comment: I was simply trying to add the software on eclipse by going through help and then install new software. I believe I found the error message now.